# HTTPd server input

Tags: ruby, http, server

I'm having problems with my server in ruby I set the request as the client or session .gets so `request = session.gets`
but when the sent request is something like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
HOST: 192.168.2.4\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n
Accept: text/xml,text/html,text/plain,image/jpeg\r\n
Accept-Language: en-us,en\r\n
```

Then `request` only returns the first line. If I do:

```
request1 = session.gets
request2 = session.gets
request3 = session.gets
request4 = session.gets
```

Then it'll work but if I put one too many `session.gets` then the client will not enter any more lines and will stop the server from running

Any ideas on what I could do to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `gets`. Either use `read` or `readlines`.

Comment: Sure! In general, unless you are reading from STDIN, don't use `gets`. It's easier to use `read` and `readlines`. Also, consider taking a look at an HTTP library. Unless you're building this for practice (in which case, great choice), it's probably easier to use a pre-built library or server unless you're building your own version of HTTP (not sure why you'd do that).

Comment: Thanks, It works the way I want it to do but the server still waits for more information, any suggestions?